# can i run api 10 android app on api 16?? any way to perform this?

Tags: java, android, api, sdk

i have developed an app on api 10 now  want to know if Android's APIs has compatibility with its newer versions ? i.e. if i installed Android API 16 can I use the application made on platform of api 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

All Android APIs are by and large backward compatible, so your app should run fine.

However, you should go through the [Highlights and Changelogs](http://developer.android.com/about/index.html) for the new versions to ensure that no API used by your app was modified in a harmful way.

Comment: Exactly. An app created for API 10 should work for on any of the later versions. Although obviously I'd recommend trying it out on either a device or the emulator...